# Is there a simple way to find slow specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

When running all specs in a project I have not touched in a while, I noticed that there seem to be 2 specs that take ages. I suspect some mocking of an API call or similar is not working anymore and the specs are running into a timeout.

Is there an easy way to identify those 2 specs without going manually through all spec files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable [profiling](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/configuration/profile-examples#setting-%60profile-examples%60-to-true-shows-10-examples) by using the `-p` flag when running `rspec`

Or you can permanently enable profiling by adding

```
config.profile_examples = true
```

or, for example,

```
config.profile_examples = 5
```

to your Rspec configuration in `spec/spec_helper.rb`.

By default, it prints the 10 slowest examples, but you can set it to a different value to have it print more or fewer slow examples.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. By the way, for my case (I only need the profiling for one run to find where the slow specs are) I found that you can also use the `-p` flag to the rspec command. Maybe you can edit your answer to include that variant as well.